# Ajax Product Filter z-index

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've got what seems to be a bug on my product filter.

Essentially there is a fixed z-index:10!important; coming from somewhere which I can't find at all.

A solution I think to get around it was to change the .js files of the filter in where it adds css but add !important to that to overwrite it.

I've tried this and it's not having it

Example -

t.parent().find('div.filterscan').css('z-index', '-1', 'important').animate({

any ideas?

**Edit 1**
So I think that z-index:10!important; entry shouldn't exist because when it's disabled it works perfectly

[Css dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDFKc.png)

Comment: usually in chrome dev tools, it does tell you where certain css is coming from. Can you check?

Comment: Unfortunately this is just showing what looks like a string after the url and no direct path back to where I can remove/change it

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the styles tab in the dev tools maybe? Then we should be able to at least see where the style comes from.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner added it

Comment: cool, when you click on the link on the right side you should be able to see where it is coming from. I also see that this is a woo commerce related style. In wordpress you have the ability to define custom css. Either pagewide or depending on the plugin, on the plugin itself.

Comment: Right, but when I click that it takes me to what looks like an auto generated php page full of html, css and jscript with that random css input in there

Comment: That's good. So custom WP css should overwrite it. :)

Comment: I tried that in the main style.css sheet to overwrite it but it's not changing it

Comment: Don't use the style sheet. Use Design (paintbrush) -> Customizer -> custom css

Comment: That worked.

Sorry was a simple answer in the end. I just over complicated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the style sheet. Use Design (paintbrush) -> Customizer -> custom css